# Project 3D Object on a plane

Tags: scripting, export

I have 3D Objects I want to convert to 2D Geometries by projecting onto a plane. Is that possible with Blender? If possible in an automatic way. An export to a Shapefile would be fine too.

For instance, I have a 3D building and I would like to get the 2D Geometry as if the Object were parallel projected on the ground plane (for instance the x-z-plane).

A box/cube would either become a rectangle or an hexagon depending on the rotation.

[image: hexagon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a plane on the axis you want (for instance x, z).

Add a shrinkwrap modifier to your mesh and set this plane as target object (mode = 'nearest surface point').

[image]

Of course you can also scale to zero along an axis... but the shrinkwrap allows to do it in a none destructive way and to project to any plane.

Comment: Does this require cleaning up the mesh afterwards (intersecting vertices, z-fighting, etc.), or is that handled in the modifier?

Comment: the shape is just flatten. For the rest, nothing changes about its faces or edges (so for instance, that does not calculate intersections).