# Project a 3D object into a 2D object

Tags: mesh, project

I'd like to create a 2D object (outline only), as a projection of a 3D object on a plane; for example, I would like the outline I see from the top view (the orange loop, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBklk.jpg)), to be a 2D object/mesh. There is [another topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60600/project-3d-object-on-a-plane) mentioning something similar, but the result in that case is not an outline. I guess what I'm asking is like the "knife project", but for arbitrary objects. The model I'm working on is [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bk1g39pkko8myc/prop.blend?dl=1) (I want its top view outline).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, do you have pictures of what you want? What does ""knife project", but for arbitrary objects" means?

Comment: Hi, according to the blender docs, knife projection can only be used when the projected object has "wireframe or boundary edges", thus being limited only to some objects (planes, not cubes for example). Essentially, I want the 2D outline of an object under any angle (top view for example). The orange, 2D outline in [this image](https://imgur.com/YcHIPKG) is what I'm interested in.

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/svg-output-script/566412

Comment: if you apply the shrinkwrap modifier - you have a 2D object. What do you mean with "extracted"!? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMECv.gif

Comment: @Chris, I didn't apply the modifier, my bad. But now, I get a flattened mess with no way to select the outline that I want (Select Loops > ... do not work).

Comment: I realized very late, that you just want the outline…because you just wrote this in the comments, but not in the question. Unfortunately I don’t know how to just get the outline except do it manually…so select all inner vertices, delete them and then create the new face by selecting all vertices and tap „F“

Comment: @Chris Right, I should update the question, thanks for the help. I'm working with high-poly models so anything manual is out of the question. The problem is, not all vertices are linked in the flattened mesh. Another way might be to create vertices where edges intersect (with the tinyCAD add-on for example) and later select the boundary loop, but the runtimes are too big (30min+ in total).

Comment: @batFINGER your script created some artifacts in my case. Also, that's a bisection, not a projection. A projection would be like the shadow casted on a plane for example (and I want the outline of that shadow). I also tried using freestyle but didn't quite get there. The boolean modifier, again, introduced some artifacts on the section it produced. Nevertheless, it seems Blender does not have such function for projections/outlines and none of the solutions I tried seemed satisfactory.

Comment: Would say the bisect technique used is  a "cheap immitation" of an ORTHO projection.   Edited answer to include another answer which projects an object using camera matrix. (PERSP or ORTHO) Could change up to project on some plane behind the object in relation to camera to emulate a shadow.  Agree with comments above, [edit] any extra detail into question, including what your test case is, and IMO always better to have images inline rather than as links if possible.

Comment: It still creates artifacts and still acts as a bisection (I can tell because my model has a hole in the middle). At this point I'll ask for permission to upload the model as nothing seems to be working with it. But Blender seems to be doing well outlining the model when I select it, so there must be something wrong with your script, right?

Comment: @batFINGER nothing seems to be working with [my model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bk1g39pkko8myc/prop.blend?dl=1), any ideas? (I just want the outline of the top view).

Comment: Second technique  outlined is not a bisection.  Please [edit] any extra details you may have into question.

Comment: @batFINGER aligning the camera, selecting the object, running "proj" and later "dissolve" as shown in the GIF, still creates an imperfect bisection. Am I doing something wrong? My question has been marked as a duplicate and probably is, but none of the other solutions worked for me.